# Disks are mounted by themselves on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: mount, disk, unmount

I have a luks encrypted disk that I want to unmount and sleep while it's not used.

For that I use `umount /mnt/4T`, `cryptdisks_stop 4t_crypt` and finally `hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/dfafea2b-7678-445e-9ba8-b906ad63d01f` to sleep the disk.

However, after a few minutes the disk is spun up again and mounted back in `/mnt/4T` and this appears in syslog:

```
Oct 17 11:56:17 micro systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for 4t_crypt...
Oct 17 11:56:17 micro systemd[1]: Starting Automatically fetch and run repair assertions...
Oct 17 11:56:17 micro snap-repair[19134]: error: cannot use snap-repair on a classic system
Oct 17 11:56:17 micro systemd[1]: Started Automatically fetch and run repair assertions.
Oct 17 11:56:26 micro systemd-cryptsetup[19129]: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 256 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/dfafea2b-7678-445e-9ba8-b906ad63d01f.
Oct 17 11:56:28 micro systemd[1]: Started Cryptography Setup for 4t_crypt.
Oct 17 11:56:28 micro systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mapper/4t_crypt.
Oct 17 11:56:28 micro systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/mapper/4t_crypt...
Oct 17 11:56:28 micro systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Oct 17 11:56:28 micro systemd-fsck[19162]: /dev/mapper/4t_crypt: clean, 173313/244195328 files, 786566198/976754124 blocks
Oct 17 11:56:28 micro systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/mapper/4t_crypt.
Oct 17 11:56:28 micro systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/4T...
Oct 17 11:56:29 micro kernel: [2569601.089969] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Oct 17 11:56:29 micro systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/4T.
```

Any idea what might be causing this? Seems to be related to the repair assertions that seems to be related to snap-repair, but I didn't manage to find any information explaining the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone dealing with same issue - adding the `noauto` flag to both fstab and crypttab seems to have fixed this.